building a News filter using economic calendar by toodegrees
I want to extract these values from the script
a bool for cpi = flase/true for the day
string for cpi time
a bool for  nfp
string for nfp time
a bool for fomc
string for fomc time
a bool for bank holidays
.
a bool for red folder news day(if the day have a red folder news)
this will be helpful to build a news filter for later scripts. but I couldn't get these values, the script is way to advanced for me.
I tryed to extract them from S1, S2, currday values but I couldn't do it I'm a beginner
. I managed to print slot1...... slot9 on the chart but it shows a miz of not understandable numbers.... any help will be much much appreciated

If you do not post the code, please post the link of the referred indicator

The author uses request.seed What you are looking for, maybe it is in the author's Github repository

The author uses two libraries. You should also look there
